# Помогите решить проблему с шорткодом

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Вот часть шорткода.
В итоге шорткод должен выглядеть примерно так

`[my-shortcode type="gd_post_types" order="ASC" orderby="name" posts="5" taxonomy="team_tax" field="slug" cat="team-1"]`

Без вот этой части он выводит все посты из CPT `gd_post_types`

```
'tax_query' => array(
     array(
         'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy',
         'field' => 'slug',
         'terms' => 'team-1',
     )
 )
```

Как сделать так, чтоб можно было указывать с какой категории я хочу вывести посты?

```
$atts = extract( shortcode_atts(
    array (
        'type' => 'gd_post_types',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'posts' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'team_tax',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'team-1',
            )
        )
    ), $atts,
    'list-posts'
) );
// define query parameters based on attributes
$options = array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'order' => $order,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => $field,
            'terms' => $cat
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $options );

// run the loop based on the query
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <ul class="post-listing">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ошибку, вот такой шорткод у меня заработал

`[list-posts type="gd_post_types" order="DESC" orderby="date" posts="5" taxonomy="taxonomy" cat="team-1"]`

Вот такой код получился:

```
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array (
        'type' => 'gd_post_types',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'slug',
        'posts' => '-1',
        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy',
        'cat' => 'team-1',
    ), $atts,
    'list-posts'
) );
// define query parameters based on attributes
$options = array(
'post_type' => $type,
'order' => $order,
'orderby' => $orderby,
'posts_per_page' => $posts,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $cat
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $options );

// run the loop based on the query
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <ul class="post-listing">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
```